# WildFly jboss-cli.sh add datasource Mysql with useSSL=false

Tags: mysql, wildfly, datasource, keycloak, jboss-cli

I'm adding MySQL as a datasource to wildfly

I can insert the **useSSL=false** parameter to the connection-url tag via jboss-cli.sh

this works perfectly but when I launch the server it tells me to explicitly set **useSSL=false**

```
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=KeycloakMysqlDS:add(
    jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakMysqlDS, 
    driver-name=mysql, 
    connection-url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/keycloak,
    user-name=keycloak,
    password=keycloak,
    max-pool-size=15,
    min-pool-size=5
)
```

if I use this with jboss-cli.sh

```
connection-url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/keycloak?useSSL=false
```

I get this error

```
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0097: Wrong type for 'connection-url'. Expected [EXPRESSION, STRING] but was OBJECT",
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

is there a way to do this via jboss-cli.sh?

Comment: Try using `connection-url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/keycloak?useSSL=false"`.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I know, I wanted to know if you can do it directly from jboss-cli.sh to do everything from a script

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding the issue you should be able to. You just need to enclose the value of the `connection-url` attribute in quotes.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins thanks, I did not understand ... it works

Answer (score 7):

The line fails because it contains a double assignment.
You should escape the equals sign of the url query (`useSSL\=false`).

This:

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=datasources/data-source=KeycloakMysqlDS:add( \
>     jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakMysqlDS, \
>     driver-name=mysql, \
>     connection-url=jdbcmysql://localhost:3306/keycloak?useSSL\=false, \
>     user-name=keycloak, \ 
>     password=keycloak, \
>     max-pool-size=15, \
>     min-pool-size=5 \
> )
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "response-headers" => {"process-state" => "reload-required"}
}
```

should work.